# Filipino Wife visiting England with English Husband

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

I am an Englishman living and working in Singapore, where I live with my Filipino wife.  We would like to visit UK for a month in May/June.  I have my UK passport, so no issues, but what paperwork / visa etc is needed for my Filipino Wife?  Do we need a visa? or Wedding Certificate (issued in Singapore) is sufficient?

Comment: Thank you, for your very prompt advice. I thought this was the case, so thank you for confirming

Answer (score 2):

Your wife needs a Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/tourism/yes/no